# submit form after timer

Tags: javascript, php, timer

```js
function CountDown(duration, display) {
  if (!isNaN(duration)) {
    var timer = duration,
      minutes, seconds;

    var interVal = setInterval(function() {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
      if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
        SubmitFunction();
        $('#display').empty();
        clearInterval(interVal)
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function SubmitFunction() {
  $('#submitted').html('Time is up!');
  document.getElementById('mcQuestion').submit();
}

CountDown(5, $('#display'));
```

```html
<form id="mcQuestion">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5>1. <?= $mc_q[0] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_1" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>2. <?= $mc_q[5] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=6; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_2" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>3. <?= $mc_q[10] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=11; $i < 15; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_3" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>4. <?= $mc_q[15] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=16; $i < 20; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_4" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>5. <?= $mc_q[20] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=21; $i < 25; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_5" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>6. <?= $mc_q[25] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=26; $i < 30; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_6" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>7. <?= $mc_q[30] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=31; $i < 35; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_7" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>8. <?= $mc_q[35] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=36; $i < 40; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_8" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>9. <?= $mc_q[40] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=41; $i < 45; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_9" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>

    <h5>10. <?= $mc_q[45] ?></h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
      <?php for ($i=46; $i < 50; $i++) : ?>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="mc_a_10" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?=$ mc_q[$i] ?>
      </li>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-qid="<?= $r->quiz_id ?>">Submit Answer</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I created a js for a countdown timer and the idea is that after the time set it will automatically submit the form but in my case after the countdown timer nothing happens and the timer resets back to the original time and count down again doing it endlessly.

Can you help me find the issue?

Quiz Display

```
<?php foreach ($quiz as $r) : ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <h3><?= $r->quiz_title ?></h3>
    <h3><center>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="assets\js\timer.js"></script>

    <div id="display">

    </div>
    <div id="submitted">

    </div>

    </center>
    </h3>
    <span class="help-block"><?= $r->quiz_desc ?></span>
    <p>Posted by: <?= ucwords($r->firstname).' '.ucwords($r->lastname) ?></p>
</div>

<?php if ($r->quiz_type == 1) : ?>

    <?php $questions = unserialize($r->questionnaire); ?>
    <!-- start index at 1 -->
    <?php $questions = array_combine(range(1, count($questions)), array_values($questions)); ?>

    <hr>

    <form id="tfQuestion">
        <div class="form-group">

            <?php for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) : ?>
                <div class="mb-25px">
                    <h5><?= $i.'. '.$questions[$i] ?></h5>
                    <span class="quiz-item-tf">
                        <input type="radio" name="tf-<?= $i ?>" value="True" required> True &nbsp;
                        <input type="radio" name="tf-<?= $i ?>" value="False" required> False
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php endfor; ?>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-qid="<?= $r->quiz_id ?>">Submit Answer</button>
        </div>
    </form>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php
        $answers     = unserialize($r->answers);
        $mc          = unserialize($r->quiz_mc);
        // remove all True answers
        for ($i=1; $i < 61; $i++) {
            if ($mc[$i]->value <> 'True') {
                $mc_q[] = $mc[$i]->value;
            }
        }
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <form id="mcQuestion">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>1. <?= $mc_q[0] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_1" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>2. <?= $mc_q[5] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=6; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_2" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>3. <?= $mc_q[10] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=11; $i < 15; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_3" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>4. <?= $mc_q[15] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=16; $i < 20; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_4" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>5. <?= $mc_q[20] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=21; $i < 25; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_5" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>6. <?= $mc_q[25] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=26; $i < 30; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_6" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>7. <?= $mc_q[30] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=31; $i < 35; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_7" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>8. <?= $mc_q[35] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=36; $i < 40; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_8" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>9. <?= $mc_q[40] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=41; $i < 45; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_9" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <h5>10. <?= $mc_q[45] ?></h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mcq">
                        <?php for ($i=46; $i < 50; $i++) : ?>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="mc_a_10" value="<?= $mc_q[$i] ?>" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $mc_q[$i] ?></li>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-qid="<?= $r->quiz_id ?>">Submit Answer</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Timer.js

```
function CountDown(duration, display) {
        if (!isNaN(duration)) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

          var interVal=  setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
                if (--timer < 0) {
                    timer = duration;
                   SubmitFunction();
                   $('#display').empty();
                   clearInterval(interVal)
                }
                },1000);
        }
    }

    function SubmitFunction(){
   $('#submitted').html('Time is up!');
     document.getElementById('mcQuestion').submit();
    }

     CountDown(5,$('#display'));
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you load jQuery? Why not use `$('#mcQuestion').submit();` assuming that is the form you want to submit?

Comment: Hmm let me try that "#". And what do you mean console? I am testing it in a "web" browser.
Edit:
No luck even with the # it still behave the same.
And what do you mean with 'did I load the jQuery?' @mplungjan

Comment: Hit F12 to see the console where JavaScript errors are shown. There is no actual difference between document.getElementById and $() - just one is DOM access and the other is jQuery

Comment: If your console says $ not defined, you have missed adding the jQuery library (which you use wherever we see $) to the page. `<script src="path to jQuery.js"></script>`

Comment: @mplungjan please spare abit more of time for me.

here's the error code :
Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at SubmitFunction (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:25:48)
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:15:24)

Comment: Since submitting is not at all PHP related, can you please click the `<>` button in the editor, paste in the JavaScript in the correct corner, paste in enough VIEW-SOURCE of your form to illustrate the issue and select "jQuery" on the left. Then hit TIDY and I will take a look later Right now you show TWO forms and a bunch of PHP that is hard to see the HTML through. We want a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan there you go. Althought I'm not pretty sure if i did it right.

Comment: No alas not. Add the HTML from the form from the HTML page you see when you go to your RENDERED quiz in the browser and right-click and use VIEW SOURCE. We do not need to see ANY PHP for the time being because we first need to solve your jQuery issue.

Comment: @mplungjan I really appreciate your help and time and I thank you alot for that. By the way edited it. Hope I got it right this time.

Comment: I will look when I'm get home

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks A lot I'll really look forward for it.

Comment: The code you posted in the snippet does not have any form. Let alone a form with ID mcQuestion

Comment: @mplungjan I think I got what your asking for now. Haha sorry for the trouble.

Comment: And again you have PHP in the snippet.

Comment: Haha I'm really sorry. Hmm can we talk about this outside of S.O? Like in email perhaps? That way I can send you the files if needed?

Comment: Sure - my website is in my profile

Comment: @mplungjan email sent.

Answer (score 0):

You call the countdown function everytime you display your page without checking whether you have answers are not.

You should not call that JS function CountDown(5,$('#display')); in the timer.js

You should call it inside your PHP file instead, after having checked if answers have been provided or not

Comment: Ohh I get it!! Tho the next problem lies in the submission It doesnt seem to submit it self.

Comment: Cool. :) What does your count down now? It decreases and everything stops here?

Comment: Try to specify the "method" and "action" attributes  of the form and tell me what happens.

Comment: Haven't checked yet. Im busy figuring out the submit thing. This may seem out of topic but what does "#" do?

Comment: #display means that you select the element with the id "display", if you would like to select elements with the class "display", you would have written (".display") instead

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks alot!

Comment: how do I call the function outside the js?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a index.php file please check it. form submit on timer you can pass time through in javascript  CountDown(5,div); function.

```
            <html>
            <body>
              <form action="" method="post" name="mcQuestion" id="mcQuestion">
                Name:<input type="test" name="name" value="Test">
              <div><span id="display" style="color:#FF0000;font-size:15px"></span></div>
            <div><span id="submitted" style="color:#FF0000;font-size:15px"></span></div>
            </form>
            <script>
            var div = document.getElementById('display');
            var submitted = document.getElementById('submitted');

              function CountDown(duration, display) {

                        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

                      var interVal=  setInterval(function () {
                            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                    display.innerHTML ="<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>";
                            if (timer > 0) {
                               --timer;
                            }else{
                       clearInterval(interVal)
                                SubmitFunction();
                             }

                       },1000);

                }

              function SubmitFunction(){

                submitted.innerHTML="Time is up!";
                document.getElementById('mcQuestion').submit();

               }
               CountDown(5,div);
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```